# How do I permanently disable the backup "Choose backup options" notification in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, notifications, windows-backup, windows-10-v2004

Since I've upgraded to Windows 10 version 2004, I'm getting this notification on every boot:

[image: Notification screenshot; transcription below]

> **Choose backup options to protect your pictures and documents**
>
> Your device comes with built-in options to protect your files. Choose the one that works best for you.
>
> <kbd>Turn off reminders</kbd> <kbd>View backup options</kbd>

I'm using a third-party backup solution and I'm not interested. The *Turn off reminders* button doesn't work though, it hides the notification, but it will return after reboot or the next day. *View backup options* hides the notification, but else nothing happens.

I've unchecked *Windows Backup* under *Security and Maintenance settings* in the classic Control Panel. It didn't help.

How do I permanently stop this notification? Or better, how do I make the buttons actually do what they are intended to do?

Answer (score 2):

I can right-click the notification and choose *Turn off all notifications for Backup settings*. It can be re-enabled by going to the modern *Control Panel → System → Notifications & actions* → toggle the switch next to *Windows Backup*.

This solves the problem for me, but other users may want to actually use Windows Backup in the future. I'm still looking for a solution that makes notification buttons work.

Answer (score 0):

Using ProcMon I found that disabling the backup notification results in a new DWORD in the registry:

`Enabled` with a value of `0`
here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Windows.SystemToast.BackupReminder
```